# Possible me to custom dynamic login_url for Django @login_required?

Tags: python, django, django-login

Basic way to do this decorator `@login_required` is like this;

```
@login_required(login_url='/path/to/login/')
def foobar(request):
    # do stuff
```

Here I want to make this value of `login_url` to dynamic path from `request.GET.next`. it possible for me?

**Update**, I tried with this one, but of course this should return an error `(request)` is not defined, because take before argument.

```
def dynamic_url(request):
    get_next = request.GET.get('next')
    if get_next:
        return get_next
    return '/accounts/login/'

@login_required(login_url=dynamic_url(request))
def foobar(request):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there would be a couple of way to do this:

**first** is not to use decorators and check your states inside view function like this:

```
def foo(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Do your staffs
        # get_next = request.GET.get('next')
        # if get_next:
        #     return get_next
        # return ''
```

**second** way is one I've not tested:
As I can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/) django [login_requred()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/) decorator can get a varialble called *function* and will pass decorator response to this function *(if is not None)* try to pass your *dynamic_url* function to login_required() decorator like this:

```
login_required(function=dynamic_url)
def foo(request):
    pass
```

and tell us the result :)

Comment: can you give an example please? because i found an error `if test_func(request.user): AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'user'`

Comment: @SancaKembang read this blog post for more detail :http://operatorerror.org/2012/07/create-a-custom-authentication-decorator-in-django/